# Return Data for each day of week (7 records for each row)- MySQL

Tags: mysql, dayofweek, days

The query I have at the moment gives me data for a selected date. I would like to have a percentage for each day of the week from the selected date for the next 7 days:

```
select distinct(shift_report.advisor), team, shift_report.date as week_commencing, SUM(shift_report.time) as total_time, round(SUM(shift_report.time)/450 * 100,2) as percentage 
from shift_report
where `date` >=20160223
AND `date`<=20160301
AND `team`=4
GROUP BY shift_report.advisor ORDER BY percentage DESC;
```

I would like to see:

Advisor | Team | week_commencing | total_time | % day 1 | % day 2 | % day 3 and so on for 7 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working using the following:

```
SELECT advisor, 
MIN(shift_report.date) AS week_commencing, 
ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.date = %%sdate%%, shift_report.time, 0)) / 450,2) AS Day1, 
ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.date = %%sdate%% + INTERVAL 1 DAY, shift_report.time, 0)) / 450,2) AS Day2, 
ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.date = %%sdate%% + INTERVAL 2 DAY, shift_report.time, 0)) / 450,2) AS Day3, 
ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.date = %%sdate%% + INTERVAL 3 DAY, shift_report.time, 0)) / 450,2) AS Day4, 
ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.date = %%sdate%% + INTERVAL 4 DAY, shift_report.time, 0)) / 450,2) AS Day5, 
ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.date = %%sdate%% + INTERVAL 5 DAY, shift_report.time, 0)) / 450,2) AS Day6, 
ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.date = %%sdate%% + INTERVAL 6 DAY, shift_report.time, 0)) / 450,2) AS Day7 
FROM shift_report WHERE date >=%%sdate%% 
%%team%% 
GROUP BY shift_report.advisor;
```

NOTE: The %%sdate%% and %%team%% are replaced with data passed in from php page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a condition statement within the SUM aggregate function, so count for each day:-

```
SELECT shift_report.advisor, 
    shift_report.team, 
    MIN(shift_report.`date`) AS week_commencing, 
    SUM(shift_report.time) as total_time, 
    ROUND(SUM(shift_report.time)/450 * 100,2) as percentage, 
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160223, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day1,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160224, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day2,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160225, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day3,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160226, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day4,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160227, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day5,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160228, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day6,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160229, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day7,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160301, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day8
FROM shift_report
WHERE `date` >=20160223
AND `date`<=20160301
AND `team`=4
GROUP BY shift_report.advisor, 
        shift_report.team
ORDER BY percentage DESC;
```

EDIT

If you just want to insert 1 date then you can do it like this:-

```
SELECT shift_report.advisor, 
    shift_report.team, 
    MIN(shift_report.`date`) AS week_commencing, 
    SUM(shift_report.time) as total_time, 
    ROUND(SUM(shift_report.time)/450 * 100,2) as percentage, 
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = start_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day1,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = plus_1_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day2,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = plus_2_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day3,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = plus_3_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day4,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = plus_4_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day5,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = plus_5_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day6,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = plus_6_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day7,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = end_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day8
FROM shift_report
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT '2016-02-23' AS start_date, 
            DATE_ADD('2016-02-23',INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AS plus_1_date,
            DATE_ADD('2016-02-23',INTERVAL 2 DAY ) AS plus_2_date,
            DATE_ADD('2016-02-23',INTERVAL 3 DAY ) AS plus_3_date,
            DATE_ADD('2016-02-23',INTERVAL 4 DAY ) AS plus_4_date,
            DATE_ADD('2016-02-23',INTERVAL 5 DAY ) AS plus_5_date,
            DATE_ADD('2016-02-23',INTERVAL 6 DAY ) AS plus_6_date,
            DATE_ADD('2016-02-23',INTERVAL 7 DAY ) AS end_date
) sub01
WHERE `date` BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
AND `team`=4
GROUP BY shift_report.advisor, 
        shift_report.team
ORDER BY percentage DESC;
```

If you just want to insert 1 date in 1 place then something like this:-

```
SELECT shift_report.advisor, 
    shift_report.team, 
    MIN(shift_report.`date`) AS week_commencing, 
    SUM(shift_report.time) as total_time, 
    ROUND(SUM(shift_report.time)/450 * 100,2) as percentage, 
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = start_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day1,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = plus_1_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day2,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = plus_2_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day3,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = plus_3_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day4,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = plus_4_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day5,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = plus_5_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day6,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = plus_6_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day7,
    ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = end_date, shift_report.time, 0)) / SUM(shift_report.time), 2) AS Day8
FROM shift_report
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT base_start_date AS start_date, 
            DATE_ADD(base_start_date,INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AS plus_1_date,
            DATE_ADD(base_start_date,INTERVAL 2 DAY ) AS plus_2_date,
            DATE_ADD(base_start_date,INTERVAL 3 DAY ) AS plus_3_date,
            DATE_ADD(base_start_date,INTERVAL 4 DAY ) AS plus_4_date,
            DATE_ADD(base_start_date,INTERVAL 5 DAY ) AS plus_5_date,
            DATE_ADD(base_start_date,INTERVAL 6 DAY ) AS plus_6_date,
            DATE_ADD(base_start_date,INTERVAL 7 DAY ) AS end_date
    FROM
    (
        SELECT '2016-02-23' AS base_start_date
    ) sub2
) sub1
WHERE `date` BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
AND `team`=4
GROUP BY shift_report.advisor, 
        shift_report.team
ORDER BY percentage DESC;
```

Note that both of these avoid doing the date calculations in the WHERE clause (which could otherwise possibly trigger a calculate for ever row of data, rather than just once for the query)

Comment: thanks, the code you gave worked once i added the time I need it to work out the %. Is there anyway to automate so the input would be start date and the remainder could be worked out based on the start date, without having to manually enter each - i'm using this for reporting and have a GUI that passes in some of the data.

Comment: You could inner join against a sub query that returns the first date and calculates the last date (so the sub query returns 1 row), then do the date check in the ON clause of the join. You can then calculate the others dates as start date + X days for each of the columns.

Comment: Hi @kickstart The 'start date' will be fed in via a gui. What I would like the query to do is give me 7 days worth of the % column output from that date. The query above works perfectly, but I'm unable to manually type in each date. Thanks for your comment above - I'm not really sure how to do what you have suggested??

Comment: @GrahamDrummond - Added some solutions which avoid having to precalculate the dates before the query., and which should avoid having to calculate the dates for every row of data.

Comment: Thanks @kickstart that's how I got it working using base + interval 1day and so on.

Comment: @GrahamDrummond - yes, but your solution is doing the calculation of base + interval in the SELECT part, and as such is probably having to do the calculation for every row that matches the WHERE clause.. My solutions do this in a sub query to get those dates, hence should only have to do the calculation once irrespective of how many rows you return.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?
It's a little hard-coded, and you could try and make it more sophisticated, but that's a basic principal you could utilize:

```
    SELECT advisor, team, week_commencing, total_time, 
           max(case when `date` = 20160223 then percentage end) day_1,
           max(case when `date` = 20160224 then percentage end) day_2,
           max(case when `date` = 20160225 then percentage end) day_3,
           max(case when `date` = 20160226 then percentage end) day_4,
           max(case when `date` = 20160227 then percentage end) day_5,
           max(case when `date` = 20160228 then percentage end) day_6,
           max(case when `date` = 20160229 then percentage end) day_7
    FROM (
       select distinct(shift_report.advisor) AS advisor, team,
             shift_report.date as week_commencing, SUM(shift_report.time) as    total_time, 
             round(SUM(shift_report.time)/450 * 100,2) as percentage 
       from shift_report
       where `date` >=20160223
         AND `date`<=20160301
         AND `team`=4
       GROUP BY shift_report.advisor ORDER BY percentage DESC
    ) your_query
   GROUP BY advisor, team, week_commencing, total_time;
```

Comment: Hi @dougiehauser thanks for this, for some reason the query fails at the line:  max(case when date = 20160223 then percentage end) day_1, advising unknown column 'date' in field list.

Comment: maybe it's because "date" is a reserved word... maybe try using `date` (i mean, back-apostraphe, stackoverflow keeps changing it... anyway, I've updated my answer... see if that helps)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses so far, I now have it displaying the correct data using:

```
SELECT shift_report.advisor, 
shift_report.team, 
MIN(shift_report.`date`) AS week_commencing, 
SUM(shift_report.time) as total_time, 
ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160223, shift_report.time, 0)) / 450,2) AS Day1,
ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160224, shift_report.time, 0)) / 450,2) AS Day2,
ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160225, shift_report.time, 0)) / 450,2) AS Day3,
ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160226, shift_report.time, 0)) / 450,2) AS Day4,
ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160227, shift_report.time, 0)) / 450,2) AS Day5,
ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160228, shift_report.time, 0)) / 450,2) AS Day6,
ROUND(100 * SUM(IF(shift_report.`date` = 20160229, shift_report.time, 0)) / 450,2) AS Day7
```

FROM shift_report
WHERE `date` >=20160223
AND `team`=4
GROUP BY shift_report.advisor
ORDER BY total_time DESC;

Is there anyway I can use the first day and automate the remaining 6 days based on first date input?